# Как правильно настроить C# методы, чтобы при работе с ними из свойств в другом классе нельзя было обойти get свойство через внутренние методы и ссылки

Tags: c#

Основной класс,  с какой-то логикой:

```
class A
{
    private int i = 0;
    public int I
    { 
        get => i;
        set => i = value;
    }
    public int GetI()
    {
        return i;
    }
    public void SetI(int I)
    {
        this.I = I;
    }
}
```

Класс, где нужно чтобы можно было только читать переменную, но не в коем образе ее не изменять, даже через методы встроенные в класс A:

```
class B
{
    private A aa = new A();
    public A AA
    {
        get => aa;
    }
}
```

Пример уже работы с классом B:

```
B b = new B();
Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);//выведет 0
b.AA.I = 1;
Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);//выведет 1
b.AA.SetI(2);
Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);//выведет 2
```

Собственно, как реализовать в классе A, логику, если он находится в свойстве которое не имеет set свойство, чтобы не работали некоторые функции.

Comment: `get => aa;` => `get => new A(){I=aa.I};`?

Comment: В целом, как фикс можно использовать, но хотелось бы чтобы в самом классе A была проверка, конечно я не знаю реализуемо такое или нет, но в целом - спасибо вам

Comment: Конечно можно добавить внутри класса A bool переменную отвечающую за это и при создании объекта в конструкторе запрашивать ее, но с какой-то стороны это фикс проблемы, а не решение ее

Comment: _в самом классе A была проверка_ - это нереализуемо, так как сам класс не знает, где и как его будут использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать интерфейс

```
interface IReadOnlyA
{
    int I { get; }
    int GetI();
}

class A : IReadOnlyA
{
    // ...тот же самый код
}

class B
{
    private A aa = new A();
    public IReadOnlyA AA
    {
        get => aa;
    }
}
```

Получится так

```
B b = new B();
Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);
b.AA.I = 1; // CS0200 Property or indexer 'IReadOnlyA.I' cannot be assigned to --it is read only
Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);
b.AA.SetI(2); // CS1061 'IReadOnlyA' does not contain a definition for 'SetI' and no accessible extension method 'SetI' accepting a first argument of type 'IReadOnlyA' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)
Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);
```

Comment: `(A)b.AA` и готово

Comment: @Grundy для этого есть модификаторы видимости, класс можно сделать приватным или интернал, интерфейс публичным. В самом .NET эта практика очень распространена.

Comment: Тогда, получается, если использовать ваш метод реализации, то можно класс B править как:
```
class B
{
    public IReadOnlyA AA = new A();
}
```
Если конечно в свойстве AA не будет логики

Comment: @aepot, там кроме интерфейсов, есть и сами ReadOnly классы.

Comment: @Mina987 тогда уж `public readonly IReadOnlyA AA = new A();`, если полем. Или `public IReadOnlyA AA { get; } = new A();` если свойством

Comment: @Grundy в любом случае оно всё на абстракциях работает. И если уж на то пошло, рефлексию никто не отменял. Здесь скорее инкапсуляция для комфортной разработки, минимизация ошибок, а не защита от жуликов.

Comment: @aepot, про рефлексию никто и не говорил. но в указанном подходе, вполне может быть и случайное обращение, например при использовании того же dynamic. А для минимизации ошибок нет смысла делать интерфейс, ты и так знаешь где можно изменить, а где -нет

Comment: @Grundy для таких случаев члены класса объявляются приватными или защищенными. Все зависит от потребностей. Существуют же интерфейсы `IReadOnlyList<T>` или `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` - как раз для того же самого, о чем писал автор. Вполне валидная практика. Если же автору мое предложение не подходит, можно уточнить и дополнить вопрос. Судя по тому, что ответ уже принят, решение рабочее. В рамках текущего вопроса мудрить глубже нет никакого смысла.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, я нашел недочет вашего метода, к примеру
```
        B b = new B();
        A aa = (A)b.AA;
        Console.WriteLine(aa.I);
        Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);
        aa.I = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(aa.I);
        Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);
        aa.SetI(2);
        Console.WriteLine(aa.I);
        Console.WriteLine(b.AA.I);
```
данный пример, показывает то, что всё же обход есть, конечно-же я сейчас поизучаю ```IReadOnlyList<T>``` и ```IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>```

Comment: @Mina987 так от кого и чего вы хотите защититься? От себя или от плохих разработчиков? У вас отдельная сборка или что? Что еще можно ответить имея только то что опубликовано в вопросе? Задайте отдельный вопрос, обозначьте проблему, которую пытаетесь решить, укажите как можно больше подробностей. А пока непонятно, зачем вы создаете публичные члены в классе, которые не должны быть доступны публично. Решение наверняка есть, но имея то что имеем - его не угадать.